# Shortcut of zooming out in Windows in Parallels Desktop

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, parallels-desktop

I have a french keyboard. I try to use Windows 10 via `Parallels Desktop` under Mac.

In Mac, in Chrome we use `cmd + =` and `cmd + -` to zoom in and zoom out. It is the same in VS Code.

But in Windows, it does not work well:

1) in Chrome, `control + -` can zoom in, whereas I have not found the shortcut to zoom out.

2) in VS Code, `control + -` can zoom in, whereas I have not found the shortcut to zoom out. In the setting it is written that the shortcut for zooming out is `control + NumPad_Subtract`, but what is the key?

Could anyone help?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic since it's actually about Windows, not macOS, as the host OS is unimportant here. Superuser might be a better place to ask.

Comment: The Windows is in a Virtual Machine of macOS, that's the reason why these shortcuts don't work as in a normal Windows... @JMY1000

Comment: I'm not sure why that'd be the case. How do you know that's what's happening, and it's not something in the guest OS?

Answer (score 1):

[Per Google, it is <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> to zoom in and <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> to zoom out on a French keyboard.](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=fr)

I'm not sure exactly which shortcut you're referring to since there's multiple zooms (12 by my count), but a [full list of French shortcuts can be found here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/da5kh0wa.aspx)

It's possible that your keyboard layout is misconfigured. [Ensure it's properly configured by performing the following steps:](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-your-keyboard-layout-windows-10)

> 1. Click on the Start Menu.
> 2. Click on Settings.
> 3. Click on Time & language.
> 4. Click on Region & language.
> 5. Click on the language you wish to add a keyboard layout to.
> 6. Click on Options.
> 7. Click on Add a keyboard.
> 8. Click on the keyboard you want to add.